# Multiple Socket Connection Using PHP

Tags: php, phpwebsocket

I have made a socket connection using php which is working perfectly below is the code for single socket but not working with multiple connections only accepts one connection at a time

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// sudo lsof -t -i:10000 
// php -f server.php
/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
 * as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '192.168.5.155';
$port = 3490;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 1024) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Send instructions. */
    $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ))) {
            /*echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;*/
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break 2;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";
        if($buf != '')
        {
            $req_get = $talkback;
            $file = time();
            $fp = fopen('data/'.$file.'.txt', 'a+');
            fwrite($fp, $req_get);

            fclose($fp);
            socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        }        
        //echo "$buf\n";    
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
```

**I need a help to just make it work with multiple connection with clients.**
After that i need to make entry into database from client sent data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't listen many sockets using blocking socket connections at the same time. What you need is [non-blocking socket connections](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.socket-set-nonblock.php) with [socket_select](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) method instead of `socket_accept`.

My suggestion is to use some kind of PHP event-loop implementations (like [reactphp](https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop)).

Anyway, if you still want to implement it yourself, you can check the example of `stream_select` usage in [reactphp/event-loop StreamSelectLoop implementation](https://github.com/reactphp/event-loop/blob/master/src/StreamSelectLoop.php#L170).